# Visual Studio with React project keeps starting multiple copies of the development server

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 with the React template on .NET (core) 6.

When I press f5 to start debugging, it starts a command prompt to start the development proxy server, fires up my deafult browser (chrome), and everything seems to work OK.

However, about every 2 minutes after, regardless of whether I have touched VS or the app, it then starts another copy of the development server, which then gets stuck with a prompt saying Something is already running on port 3000. Left to its own devices it just keeps starting more.

This doesn't stop the previous one working but it's frustrating to have all these windows appearing, especially as they steal focus when prompting with the "port in use".

Something that I suspect is related is a message appearing in the debug output around every 8 seconds saying "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyMiddleware: Information: SPA proxy is not ready. Returning temporary landing page." However as noted above the SPA proxy certainly seems to be running OK.

Has anyone got any ideas what might be happening or any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

OK I managed to figure this out by creating another blank project and comparing them.

The port that the development server will listen on is stored in a file called `ClientApp\.env.development`; the port that visual studio expects it to listen on is in the `.csproj` file under `PropertyGroup/SpaProxyServerUrl`. If there is a mismatch you will get this behaviour because VS thinks the server isn't running and keeps on trying to start it.

In my case I had added the `.env.development` file to the version control ignore list thinking it wasn't important. This was causing the dev server to listen on the default port 3000.

Comment: Thank you, this solved our problem too! A related issue we were running into was that it was opening 2 browser windows each time we ran the project. The default .env file has a `BROWSER=none` flag that had gotten removed somewhere along the line. Putting that flag back in set it back to only opening one window.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with multiple NPM terminals opening every few minutes and nothing loading in the browser that starts up. Both my `.env development` and `SpaProxyServerUrl` use 44442.